# WHM Unable to Change Wordpress Max Upload Size

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, size, whm

I have several Wordpress installs in a WHM Environment. My WHM PHP(5.6) max upload size is set to 100MB & PHP max POST size 150MB. I also check MultiPHP INI Editor and the max upload size is the same. But for some reason all my Wordpress installs have a max upload size of 8MB. I cannot get it to change.

I've tried the following:

- Added php.ini file, but does not help/change
- Added php code to the .htaccess, but it causes a Internal Server Error
- Added php code to the theme's function.php, but it causes a Internal Sever Error
- Spoke with HostGator customer server for a couple hours and they were not able to help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to add these lines in your theme functions.php

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
```

Or verify your php.ini files and change these values

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Or add this in your .htaccess files

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
```

You should restart your apache server after changing the php.ini file to take effect on your hosting.

If you are using Wordpress multisites you can have a restriction from Wordpress itself you find it under **Settings -> Network settings -> Maximum file size**

Comment: I've tried all 3 suggest before, but I did them again to make sure, and still no luck. Max upload is still 8MB.

Answer (score -1):

If you don’t want coding, directly increase max upload size through this free plugin https://ziscom.today/max-upload-size/

After installation go to WordPress menu ‘Max Upload Size’
* Only enter the numeric value in bytes
* 1024 bytes = 1KB
* 1048576 bytes = 1MB

It worked for me. Hope it help for you.

Comment: You need to provide any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. See more details on how to answer at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You posted 3 answers in 10 minutes promoting the same templates/site. That makes these answers look like spam. Are you associated with this product in any way? If you are affiliated, you *must disclose that affiliation in the post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).